# Is it ok to use special characters in xbrl context names

Tags: xbrl

Is it fine to use special characters in xbrl context IDs?
If not, could anyone throw some light on the characters that can be used? I went through the  xbrl 2.1 specification(section 4.7.1 regarding the id attribute), but im not able to understand what characters are allowed. 
In some example XBRLs, the special characters were omitted. I'm using certain domain member values for forming context names, so I'm not sure if I should omit special characters or if I should retain them.
Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the  ID attribute must conform to the XML rules for attributes with the ID type. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name, they must start with one of the following characters:

- ":"
- any character in the range [A-Z]
- "_" any character in the range [a-z]
- any character in the range [#xC0-#xD6]
- any character in the range [#xD8-#xF6]
- any character in the range [#xF8-#x2FF]
- any character in the range [#x370-#x37D]
- any character in the range [#x37F-#x1FFF]
- any character in the range [#x200C-#x200D]
- any character in the range [#x2070-#x218F]
- any character in the range [#x2C00-#x2FEF]
- any character in the range [#x3001-#xD7FF]
- any character in the range [#xF900-#xFDCF]
- any character in the range [#xFDF0-#xFFFD]
- any character in the range [#x10000-#xEFFFF]

The other characters in the name can be any character from the list above, or, additionally, one of the following characters:

- "-"
- "."
- any character in the range [0-9]
- #xB7
- any character in the range [#x0300-#x036F]
- any character in the range [#x203F-#x2040]